# How to use jwt from anotherfile inside a post request

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm trying to get my token and verify it from another file ( jwt.js ) inside my main ( app.js ) just to make it more organized but when I attempt to export from jwt.s to app.js it doesn't work and postman post request gets stuck on loading for ever ( it works when I put all of the code inside my main which is app.js )

Here's my code inside jwt.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

function verifyJWT() {
  jwt.verify(req.token, "fortest", (err, authData) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
      res.json(
        `Logged in with ${req.token} and here is some data for you ${authData}`
      );
    }
  });
}

function signJWT() {
  jwt.sign({}, "fortest", (err, token) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(511);
    } else {
      res.json({ token });
    }
  });
}

// Verifies the Token
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const headers = req.headers["authorization"];
  if (typeof headers !== "undefined") {
    const tokenArray = headers.split(" ");
    const theToken = tokenArray[1];
    req.token = theToken;
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
}

module.exports.verifyJWT = verifyJWT;
module.exports.signJWT = signJWT;
module.exports.verifyToken = verifyToken;
```

And this is my code inside app.js ( my main )

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const jwt = require("./jwt"); // they are in same folder

// Wants the token
app.post("/api/login", jwt.verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  jwt.verifyJWT;
});

// Gives the token
app.post("/api/token", (req, res) => {
  jwt.signJWT;
});
```

Comment: If they're functions you need to call them, i.e. `jwt.verifyJWT(req, res)`. Or just pass it to express: `app.post("/api/login", jwt.verifyToken, jwt.verifyJWT);`

Comment: @ThomasSmyth thanks for the reply, I've tried both calling `jwt.signJWT()` and `app.post("/api/token", jwt.signJWT)` none of them worked sadly

Comment: `jwt.verifyJWT` need the params added to it too, I didn't spot that at first. `function verifyJWT(req, res) {`

Comment: @ThomasSmyth But `jwt.signJWT` doesn't have any params to it, what about it?

Comment: That needs to have it too. Wherever you use `req` or `res` they need to be defined, AKA you need to pass the value to them as parameters in the function definitions.

Comment: now I see!! Thanks a lot, it worked, can you send it as an answer so that I can choose it as best answer in case someone else had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes with your code.

Firstly, when you wish to use a function you must call it using `()`. Otherwise, it acts like a variable, i.e. you can assign a new value to it or use it to assign another variable.

```
app.post("/api/login", jwt.verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  jwt.verifyJWT;
});
```

Should be...

```
app.post("/api/login", jwt.verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  jwt.verifyJWT(req, res);
});
```

However, as Express call the functions you pass in the `post()` method arguments, you could more simply put:

```
app.post("/api/login", jwt.verifyToken, jwt.verifyJWT);
```

The second mistake, is that you use undefined variables in your functions in the jwt.js file. You must pass those values as arguments to use.

```
function verifyJWT() {
  jwt.verify(req.token, "fortest", (err, authData) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
      res.json(
        `Logged in with ${req.token} and here is some data for you ${authData}`
      );
    }
  });
}

function signJWT() {
  jwt.sign({}, "fortest", (err, token) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(511);
    } else {
      res.json({ token });
    }
  });
}
```

Should be...

```
function verifyJWT(req, res) {
  jwt.verify(req.token, "fortest", (err, authData) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
      res.json(
        `Logged in with ${req.token} and here is some data for you ${authData}`
      );
    }
  });
}

function signJWT(req, res) {
  jwt.sign({}, "fortest", (err, token) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(511);
    } else {
      res.json({ token });
    }
  });
}
```